# Generate more plots separate in figure in one script in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

First of all, I apologies if this question was already asked and answered, I haven't found anything really specific about this so if you did, please share and I will delete this post.
What I would like to do is simply generate more separate plots after one another in separate figure in python, because I have an exercise sheet and the a) is to plot a poisson distribution and the b) is to plot a binomial distribution and so ever with c) and d), and I would like that the plots are gathered together in the same script but in separate figure.

I tried as simple as create a sin(x) and a cos(x) plot after one another but it didn't work, the sin and cos were displaying in the same plot.. My code was:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.plot(np.sin(x))
ax2 = plt.plot(np.cos(x))
ax1.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax1.set_title('sin')
ax1.legend()
ax2.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax2.set_title('cos')
ax2.legend()

plt.show()
```

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
ax1.plot(np.sin(x))
ax2.plot(np.cos(x))

plt.show()
```

I suggest you should read a [simple tutorial about subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/create_subplots.html).

EDIT:
To create separate figures:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.sin(x))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.cos(x))

plt.show()
```

Comment: This creates two plots in one subplot, but doenst not create two separate plots do you know what I mean ? I really want separate pictures

Comment: omg thanks it works! It's exaclty what I wanted, thank you :))